# Custom changeset validation for insert action alone

Tags: model, crud, elixir, phoenix-framework

Am working on Phoenix project. I have the following model:

```
defmodule MyApp.Exam do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  alias Ecto.Changeset
  alias MyApp.Repo
  alias MyApp.TimexHelper
  alias Timex.Date

  import Ecto.Query

  schema "exams" do
      field :start_time, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
      belongs_to :student, Student

      timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(student_id start_time)

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
      model
      |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
      |> assoc_constraint(:student)
      |> is_in_future(:start_time)
  end

  def is_in_future(changes, field) do
      new_time = Changeset.get_field(changes, field)
      valid = TimexHelper.compare(new_time, Date.now)
      if !valid, do: changes = Changeset.add_error(changes, field, "should be in the future")
      changes
  end
end
```

How do I make the custom validation `is_in_future` for the field `start_time` to be executed only during `insert` operation ?

I tried adding a `if` condition inside `is_in_future` to check if `start_time` is available. But I don't think that's a better solution.

Am looking for something like:

```
# Rails model field validation
validates_presence_of :start_time, :on => :create
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think there is no solution like rails. You will create the changeset and validation before your database call will do. After that you insert/update the model by yourself. The cast method has no informations about the database call after your validation.

My idea is to add a parameter like a boolean or an atom to changeset function to define your type of validation.

```
func changeset(model, params \\ :empty, type \\ :insert) do
  changeset = model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> assoc_constraint(:student)

  case type do
    :insert ->
      is_in_future(changeset, :start_time)
    :update ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

Then you should call `changeset(model, params, :insert)` or `changeset(model, params, :update)`.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
An other idea is to checkout if the `id` of model is set to `nil`. This is like your idea with the existing `start_time` field.